# Delay ReactiveUI validation after typing

Tags: c#, validation, reactiveui, avalonia

I want to check if the typed username already exists in the database. I've got an async query, but i don't want to check it after every typed character but 1s after typing finished.

Here is what i've got so far:

```
[Reactive]
public string? Username{ get; set; }

[ObservableAsProperty]
public bool IsUsernameExists{ get; }
...
this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.Username)
.Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000))
.Select(x => this.UserNameExists.ExecuteAsync(x))
.Select(x => x.Result)
.ToPropertyEx(this, vm => vm.IsUsernameExists);

this.ValidationRule(x => x.Username, x => !this.IsUsernameExists, "Username already exists.");
```

The problem is, when Username changed, the validation evaluates IsUsernameExists before it is updated because of the delay. So the validation is always 1 character behind typing.
Does anyone know a solution for the problem?

Thanks in advance,
Imre Horvath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got it working:

```
        this.ValidationRule(
            vm => vm.Name,
            this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.Name)
            .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.7), RxApp.TaskpoolScheduler)
            .SelectMany(async x => (await this.BankNameExists.ExecuteAsync(x)) == true ?
            new ValidationState(false, "Name already exists.") : ValidationState.Valid)
            .ObserveOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler));
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**